# Migration from SAP HANA to Snowflake, problem in building SAP HANA hierarchy dataset in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In SAP HANA we have some datasets build on top of hierarchy functions such as HIERARCHY_ANCESTORS & HIERARCHY_DESCENDANTS where we extensively use attributes(hierarchy_level , hierarchy_rank & start_rank) from these functions to build complex BOM (bill of materials) tree data sets with all possible permutation and combination.

Now when we migrate to snowflake to build the same data sets, I can use recursive CTE to build the BOM but I do not get all the possible permutation and combination which I get with HANA hierarchy functions.

Comment: You are probably going to have to explain how the SAP hierarchies work, with some sample data to illustrate it, so that someone who knows Snowflake can suggest possible solutions